# Get the closest path graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have an oriented graph
where

```
1 - From 
2 - To
3 - Start time (HH:mm, casted to integer) 60 => 01:00
4 - difference between endtime, always > 0;



1 2 60 120
1 2 720 125
1 2 900 120
1 3 390 90
1 3 1040 95
2 3 780 180
2 3 1260 180
2 4 240 240
2 4 300 240
2 4 1080 240
3 1 165 90
3 1 1430 90
3 2 1432 180
3 5 1431 249
4 2 1080 240
4 3 720 60
```

Lets forget about start time column, but **what could be the easiest algorithm to get Closest path**, from 1 to 5, it means, by getting closest path where fourth column sum is the less one..

To mention: i have no real nodes mades, i just have information about edges, which I am writing in array like

```
edges[ ''counter'' ] [0] = from;
edges[ ''counter'' ] [1] = to;
edges[ ''counter'' ] [2] = timeToInt(time);
edges[ ''counter'' ] [3] = timeToInt(endTime) - edges[ ''counter'' ] [2];
```

I've heard of [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) , but how to implement.

Comment: Open your IDE an start coding.

Comment: All the algorithms are based on nodes, but the vectors that joins them, should i create additional array for nodes?

Comment: I've had an experience with Dijkstra, a 2D array is suitable to represent the graph and apply algorithm on it.

Comment: But i don't have acyclic edges

Answer (score 0):

Your programming language is not relevant here, this is purely an algorithm issue. Some of your good options include:

- [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), if all edges have a non-negative cost, like in your example. Dijkstra's is fast, and fairly easy to implement. There is [an implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html) in Boost and a Google search should turn up plenty of implementations.
- [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), which is really a variety of Dijkstra's. Even faster, but heuristic, so can provide a solution that is not the best, and a bit more difficult to implement perhaps. I strongly recommend implementing A* at some point as an exercise after having implemented the basic Dijkstra's. Once again, A* [exists in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html).
- Bellman-Ford, if you need to expand to negative edge weights. Also [present in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/bellman_ford_shortest.html), and just a touch more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood rules, i had to take every closest flight that is possible...

```
// lets find all airports which allows flights from home city and so on..
int min;// minimum value
int minc;// minimal coordinate
int mine;//real position of edge in array
int fakehome = 0;// temprorary position for house
int lastmine = -1;//last position, so can compare times
//cout << timeToInt(begintime);
cout << home << " " << begintime<< endl;
fout << home << " " << begintime<< endl;
while(home != aim)// loop while we havent reached aim/target airport
{
    min = 1440;// 24(hours) * 60 is unreachable value, so 1440 minuts ok
    minc = ports;// max could be count(of airports)
    mine = edges_counter;// array position of edge
    //lastmine = -1;
    for(int i =0;i< edges_counter;i++)
    {
        //if(edges[i][0] == home) cout << edges[i][0] << " " << edges[i][1] <<  " " << edges[i][2] << " " << edges[i][3] << " " << endl;
        if(min > edges[i][2] && edges[i][0] == home && edges[i][4] == 0)
        {
            if(lastmine != -1 && (edges[lastmine][2]+edges[lastmine][3]) < edges[i][2])
            {
                min = edges[i][2];
                minc = edges[i][1];
                mine = i;
                fakehome = edges[i][1];
            }
            else if(lastmine == -1 && timeToInt(saklaiks) < edges[i][2])
            {
                min = edges[i][2];
                minc = edges[i][1];
                mine = i;
                fakehome = edges[i][1];
            }
        }
    }


    if(mine != edges_counter)
    {
        //cout << setw(3) <<  mine << " ";
        intToTime(edges[mine][2],time);
        cout << home << "->" << fakehome << " " << time;
        fout << home << "->" << fakehome << " " << time;
        intToTime((edges[mine][2]+edges[mine][3]), time);
        cout << "-"  << time<< endl;
        fout << "-"  << time<< endl;
        intToTime((edges[mine][2]+edges[mine][3]),begintime);
        home = fakehome;
        edges[mine][4] = 1;
    }
    lastmine = mine;
}
```

But there is one problem..

If

infinite loop is given for the flights and cant reach goal. How to check it?

```
If is given 
3 (how much airports)
1 3 (have to go from 1 to 3)
00:00 (start time)

1 2 01:00-02:00 (from 1 to 2 there is flight that takes 1 hour)
2 1 03:00-04:00 (from 2 to 1 there's also flight that takes 1 hour)
2 3 12:00-13:00 (...)
```

But 2->3 is never reached due to 2->1 flight being faster that 2->3
any idea knowing loop before printing first elements, cause it is printing like

```
1->2 ...
2->1 ...
1->2 ...
```

and so on..
I have to print : "Impossible".